# Using the Android TrustStore for aSmack in Android 4+ (ICS)

Tags: android, xmpp, keystore, asmack

I am not an expert on keystores and have a hard time understanding the nuances of this but this is how far I got:

In creating a xmpp-connection using the asmack build found [here](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack) one still has to change the truststore, which usually, so say multiple [sources](http://nhachicha.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/xmpp-client-with-android/) on the web, is done using these commands

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port), service);
config.setTruststorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
config.setTruststorePassword("changeit");
config.setTruststoreType("bks");
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
connection.connect();
```

This works find for older Android versions but under ICS they changed some things and now it does not anymore.The path now is diferent.

Apparently [this can be fixed](http://redmine.xabber.com/issues/212#note-3) but I have no earthly idea how.

What is needed, obviously, is a method that returns the path depending on SDK version that returns the needed string to set the sdk-path since you can not just return the keystore itself to the xmpp-connection.

In reference to [this](https://github.com/tomwhipple/AndroidPinning/blob/03d9b7d27ae3b12a946f7ac76143b7213af67579/java/org/thoughtcrime/ssl/pinning/PinningTrustManager.java) that method would look like this:

```
private String getTrustStorePath() 
{
 String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");

 if (path == null) 
 {
  if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 ) 
  {
   //THIS IS THE PART I DONT KNOW
   path="";
  }
  else
  {
   path = "/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks";
  }

  return path;
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002365/android-central-keystore) a commenter says that under Android "4.x; /etc/security/cacerts.bks was replaced with the directory/etc/security/cacerts/ containing the certs as individual PEM encoded files." however, I do not know what relevance, if any, this has.

I have also checked out the code of two projects using xmpp and asmack ([gtalksms](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/gtalksms/XmppManager.java?name=v1.9.2) and [yaxim](https://github.com/ge0rg/yaxim) but did not see how they avoid this problem.

Comment: I am also currently investigating this. We have lately [changed how we detect the truststore path on GTalkSMS](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/source/detail?r=0ce642447febaf596a49a7caf8ffb79701e657ef) as it can also be [seen here](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/wiki/Truststore). But I am pretty sure that this is not enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    connectionConfiguration.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
    connectionConfiguration.setTruststorePassword(null);
    connectionConfiguration.setTruststorePath(null);
} else {
    connectionConfiguration.setTruststoreType("BKS");
    String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
    if (path == null)
        path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
            + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
            + "cacerts.bks";
    connectionConfiguration.setTruststorePath(path);
}
```

See https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/wiki/Truststore and some background explanation at http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/ics-trust-store-implementation.html.

Comment: Hi, I used above code for Jellybean, so it works fine, also I can authenticate users. But I also see an caught exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Its thrown from proceedTLSReceived, which in turns call ServerTrustManager. It crashes for configuration.getTruststorePath().

Any idea?

Comment: @anargund I see the same issue as well. ICS and JellyBean.

Comment: @Geebs I resolved it. I downloaded latest version of jar file from asmack website. I was having problem before because I was using some old jar file. As soon as I started using latest one, most of the problems were resolved.

Comment: how to create the trust store path and those background,kindly expalin those things too @Phillip

Answer (score 1):

The trust store in ICS is not in a single .bks file any more, but in separate PEM-encoded files in the `/system/etc/security/cacerts` directory. User-added certs can be placed in `/data/misc/keychain/cacerts-added`. More details can be found **[here](http://nelenkov.blogspot.nl/2011/12/ics-trust-store-implementation.html)**.

Your cert file must be named as: `subject-hash.N` where N is an sequential integer starting from 0 (usually just 0, but if 0 is already used, then 1, etc).

To get the subject-hash of your cert, you can use openssl like this: 
 `openssl x509 -noout -subject_hash_old -in my-cert-file.pem`

Comment: Thanks but how then can one configure the connection, which requres to set a path of a truststore if this does no longer exist? `jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration` requres the use of `setTruststorePath` because at the end the result needs to be an XMPP-Connection.

Comment: Or, to go a different direction: can I create a connection without setting the trust store at all? An untrusted connection so to speak.

Comment: Have you tried the answer of Phillip? In ICS you don't need to set trust store path, only the trust store type "AndroidCAStore".

Comment: Yes, I tried and it (almost) worked (I think the error was in my surrounding code though). I have now reduced it even further, not using any kind of trustsore or encryption. Basically the bare minimum as shown [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/connections.html). This of course lacks any security but seems to work for now letting me work on other stuff...